# How to style the default color in dark mode?

Tags: tailwind-css, darkmode

I successfully configured [dark mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode) in my Vite/Vue/Tailwind app: when applying the `dark` class, any element that has a `dark:...` class is affected as expected.

This works fine on a per-element basis but I do not know how to set up defaults. Specifically, I would like to define a default dark mode font color (the one I have in light/default mode is black).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set text colors "high enough" in the DOM and it will be inherited down the tree.

The `dark` class must be somewhere "above" this setting (i.e. if the colors are set on `<body>` then `dark` must be on `<html>`). It does not have to be immediately above, though.

*Source: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/11924#discussioncomment-6857033*